# SFTP: rename/remove commands fail intermittently

Tags: sftp, ruby

I have a background job written in Ruby that connects to several SFTP servers, download some files and finally, move the downloaded files to another folder in the sftp server.

The issue is that the `rename` command fails when in just one server.

What is interesting about this issue is that **if I connect to the server using ubuntu's sftp library or using Ruby's interactive console and run the same code used by the background job, it doesn't fail.** So, it is not a permission issue.

---

**2nd approach:**

I updated the implementation with the following workaround hoping that the `remove` method will work:

```
  def move(from_path, to_path)
    sftp.rename(from_path, to_path) do |response|
      sftp.remove(from_path) unless response.ok?
    end
  end
```

The code above works for about 75% of the file by deleting them.

Any ideas of what could be the issue here?

Libraries used here are:
https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp
https://github.com/resque/resque

Comment: I'd guess that the remote file is momentarily locked by some process at the time you try to rename/move it. Might be an antivirus.

Comment: The background job runs every 2 minutes, I'm not sure this would be the case

Comment: I do not understand how the *"The background job runs every 2 minutes"* imply that it should not be the case.

Comment: Yes, my comment makes no sense. What I wanted to say is that the background job fails every 2 minutes, but if I log in at the same time and send the `rename` command, it works!

Comment: But isn't it because you have downloaded the file just before? Doesn't the download block the rename? First make sure you have really finished the download (closed the file), before trying to rename the file. And even if you are sure you do, try adding some delay between the download and the rename.

Comment: Good point but I don't think it is the case, since I'm using the `download!` method, which waits for the operation to be completed: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-sftp/2.0.5/Net/SFTP/Session#download!-instance_method - But I think we might be closing the connection before the rename command is completed, will try it!